# How to use non-commonjs library with browserify?

Tags: node.js, express, openlayers, middleware, browserify

I want to use OpenLayers with borowserify-middleware, here are my code files [app.js](https://gist.github.com/gagan-bansal/6495291), [main.js](https://gist.github.com/gagan-bansal/6495476) and [index.html](https://gist.github.com/gagan-bansal/6495438%20index.html)

I am able to display map properly, but there are few issues regarding the proper usage of browserify-middleware

- when downloaded in browser, main.js file size is double of the original files (main.js +
  OpenLayers.js), so it takes too much time to load. Why the file size
  is double? there is some encoded text at end of the file.
- how to define non-commonjs library as external? I followed the instructions as [here](https://gist.github.com/trevordixon/5747010) but could not achieve it. I have added {module.exports = OpenLayers} in the end of OpenLayers.js

Comment: Forbes Lindesay gave [detailed explanation](https://github.com/ForbesLindesay/browserify-middleware/issues/20) for this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forbes Lindesay gave [detailed explanation](https://github.com/ForbesLindesay/browserify-middleware/issues/20) for this issue.